# I feel like I have done everything correctly, but I end up on a dead end.

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Question:
\begin{equation}
    \label{simple_equation0}
 u = {\varphi }(xy)+\sqrt{xy}{\psi}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)
\end{equation}

Show that 
\begin{equation}
    \label{simple_equation1}
 x^{2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^{2}}-y^{2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^{2}}= 0
\end{equation}

[This is my work so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoivv.jpg) Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It seems that you do have $0$ at the end, don't you?

Comment: @user, I think that students will write the right-hand side as the answer they are supposed to obtain all along, and they will try to justify why the left-hand side and the right-hand side are equal. I see this often.

Comment: @Carlo I entered this question on WolframAlpha, it returns True. I don't know how.

Comment: Learning to check your own work is a very valuable skill. The higher you get the less people will be willing to check your work for you.

Comment: @user 0 is at the right side of the equation, I couldn't prove it.

Comment: @mathreadler I have already checked, nothing I could see, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: @Carlo I have seen those previous posts, they didn't show what they have done so far, also there wasn't anything valuable as answers.

Comment: @Carlo where's the first one, the one with answers on it?

Comment: @Carlo $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are functions of a single variable, so why would you need $\varphi_{xx}$ etc?

Comment: @Carlo Well, more explicitly, $\varphi(xy)$ is a composition of $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (or whatever domain and range are) and $p:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $p(x,y)=xy$. So $\varphi$ does not have partial derivatives.

Comment: @Carlo to be more explicit: $\Phi(x,y):=\varphi(xy)$  is a map $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ and has partial derivatives, but $\varphi$ itself is $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and only has ordinary derivates. (And obviously, $\Phi_x=\varphi'(xy) \cdot y$ etc. by chain rule.) So no conditions on $\varphi_{xx}$ etc are required ($\varphi$ needs to be twice differentiable, i.e. $\varphi''$ needs to exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\fr{\left(\frac yx\right)}$
We will assume $x>0,y>0$ everywhere.
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=y\phi'(xy)+\frac12\frac{y^{1/2}}{x^{1/2}}\psi\fr-\frac{y^{3/2}}{x^{3/2}}\psi'\fr
$$
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=x\phi'(xy)+\frac12\frac{x^{1/2}}{y^{1/2}}\psi\fr+
\frac{y^{1/2}}{x^{1/2}}\psi'\fr
$$
Differentiating again we obtain:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}&
=y^2\phi''(xy)-\frac14\frac{y^{1/2}}{x^{3/2}}\psi\fr
+\frac{y^{3/2}}{x^{5/2}}\psi'\fr 
+\frac{y^{5/2}}{x^{7/2}}\psi''\fr\\
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}&
=x^2\phi''(xy)-\frac14\frac{x^{1/2}}{y^{3/2}}\psi\fr
+\frac{1}{x^{1/2}y^{1/2}}\psi'\fr 
+\frac{y^{1/2}}{x^{3/2}}\psi''\fr
\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked, I wonder why though? What did I do wrong in my solution that led me to a dead end?

Comment: @Kinsky If you type your solution in MathJax I will have a look on it.

Comment: I don't really know how to type in MathJax, I added a picture of it on my post, it's a bit of a mess though, but everything is there. I understand if you don't have time to look at it.

Comment: @Kinsky To learn MathJax or generally TeX is a good investment in the future. I really do not have time to encrypt your handwriting.

Answer (score 1):

We will need $\phi$ and $\psi$ to be twice differentiable, and we note beforehand that we better restrict the domain to something like  $x,y>0$ so that the fractions and square roots involved behave well. We will use this subsequently without mention, e.g., by equating expressions like $\frac1x\sqrt {xy}$ and $\sqrt{\frac yx}$.

---

By linearity, we can consider the $\phi$-summand and the $\psi$-summand separately.
First compute the partial derivatives of $\let\phi\varphi(x,y)\mapsto \phi(xy)$.
By the chain rule, 
$$\frac\partial{\partial x}\phi(xy)=y\phi'(xy) $$
and then 
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\phi(xy)=\frac\partial{\partial x}y\phi'(xy)=y^2\phi''(xy). $$
By symmetry, likewise
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\phi(xy)=x^2\phi''(xy)$$
and so indeed 
$$x^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\phi(xy)- y^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\phi(xy)=0.$$

We treat the $\psi$-summand accordingly, it merely involves a bit more complicated derivatives:
By product and chain rule,
$$\begin{align}\frac\partial{\partial y}\bigl(\sqrt{xy}\psi(\tfrac yx)\bigr)&=\sqrt{xy}\frac\partial{\partial y}\psi(\tfrac yx)+\psi(\tfrac yx)\frac\partial{\partial y}\sqrt{xy}\\&=
\sqrt{\frac yx}\psi'(\tfrac yx)+\frac12\psi(\tfrac yx)\sqrt{\frac xy}\end{align}$$
and 
$$\begin{align}\frac\partial{\partial x}\bigl(\sqrt{xy}\psi(\tfrac yx)\bigr)&=\sqrt{xy}\frac\partial{\partial x}\psi(\tfrac yx)+\psi(\tfrac yx)\frac\partial{\partial x}\sqrt{xy}\\&=
-yx^{-2}\sqrt{\frac yx}\psi'(\tfrac yx)+\frac12\psi(\tfrac yx)\sqrt{\frac yx}\\
&=-\left(\frac yx\right)^{\frac 32}\psi'(\tfrac yx)+\frac12\psi(\tfrac yx)\sqrt{\frac yx}.\end{align}$$
So it does get a bit more complicate dthis time. I urge you to check and continue this pre-coffee (hence error-prone) calculation for the second derivative. I won't.

Instead allow we to show how one could come up with the form of solution in the first place. For this, we consider only simple functions, say power series, or even simpler polynomials, so ultimately a monomial $(x,y)\mapsto x^ny^m$. 
What happens to this under the operator $x^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}-y^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$? Fortunately, this is much easier to answer as it clearly produces
$$ \bigl(n(n-1) - m(m-1)\bigr)x^ny^m.$$
This is $\equiv 0$ iff $n(n-1)=m(m-1)$. The obvious solutions are $m=n$ (leading to $(xy)^n$ as in the $\phi$-summand) and $m-1=-n$, or a bit more symmetrically $m-\frac12=-(n-\frac12)$. This leads to   $x^ny^m=\sqrt{xy}\left(\frac yx\right)^{m-\frac12}$ as in the $\psi$-summand.